# How can I get text value of a <div> element and displaying it in another div using ng click in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

On clicking the click button the text in `ng-model=name` should get reflected in the `<h2>` tag.

```html
<div ng-model="name">This is a text</div> 
<button ng-click="getname()">Click</button>
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the div value on the fly or is it fixed? If you want to change the value, then it should be a input element because it doesn't make sense to use `ng-model` on div element

Comment: value will be fixed @Himanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="dummy">
   <div ng-bind="name"></div> 
   <button ng-click="nameCopied=name">Click</button>
   <h2 ng-show="nameCopied" ng-bind="nameCopied"></h2>
<div>
```

with this controller code:

```
app.controller('dummy', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "The text in first div";
  $scope.nameCopied = '';
});
```

See this Plunkr for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/5qwwe05CD3JTEbjAYi3m?p=info

Comment: Even this answer might say things but not helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i needed. :)

Comment: @AlexPollan - hi man, just need a little help ...go through this link http://jsfiddle.net/6uczbaab/1/    ...... i need to copy both firstname and lastname and then show it anywhere within ng-app. :/